# How to get last thursday of every month in a year 2013 in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get last Thursday of every month in a year 2013 in oracle? i need to update this date into my table.

i need a output like

```
Last Thursday in a year 2013 
----------------------
31.01.2013
28.02.2013
28.03.2013
24.04.2013
30.05.2013
27.06.2013
25.07.2013
29.08.2013
26.09.2013
31.10.2013
28.11.2013
26.12.2013
```

Thanks to do the needful.

Comment: Consider creating a [Calendar Table](http://www.perpendulum.com/2012/06/calendar-table-script-for-oracle/) and queries like this become very, very easy.

Comment: I'm not an oracle user and you haven't provided anything for us to test with, but if you have a list of month-ends you can take the day of week for each one, work out what you need to take away to get thursday, then minus that number from the month end.

Comment: @StephLocke What else could the OP provide, that you are expecting?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - whether they have a calendar table already, and ideally a cut of a table and/or query of what they've attempted so far.  You can do oracle queries on sql fiddle and with a bit more info, I'd have been able to try something based on what they already had.

Comment: Got it. The mistake was the OP didn't show any effort. :)

Comment: So, someone thought this nice question is worth a `-1`. I certainly would like to know why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will do it:

```
select next_day (last_day (add_months(date '2013-01-01', rownum-1))-7, 'THU') as thurs
from dual
connect by level <= 12;

THURS
---------
31-JAN-13
28-FEB-13
28-MAR-13
25-APR-13
30-MAY-13
27-JUN-13
25-JUL-13
29-AUG-13
26-SEP-13
31-OCT-13
28-NOV-13
26-DEC-13

12 rows selected.
```

Explanation:

1) The following `select` is a way to generate a series of integers 1..12:

```
select rownum from dual connect by level <= 12;
```

2) This returns the 1st of each of the 12 months of 2012 by taking 1st January 2013 and adding 0 months, 1 month, ..., 11 months:

```
select add_months(date '2013-01-01', rownum-1)
from dual connect by level <= 12;
```

3) The `last_day` function returns the last day of the month for the given date, so that we now have 2013-01-31, 2013-02-28, ..., 2013-12-31.

4) `next_day (date, 'THU')` returns the next Thursday after the specified date.  To get the last Thursday of the month we take the last day of the month, go back 7 days, then find the next Thursday.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Is there a NLS version of `next_day` to control the language of 'THU'?

Comment: @Tony Andrews Thanks a lot..  
select to_char(next_day 
               (last_day 
                (add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY'), rownum-1))-7, 'THU'),'DD.MM.YYY')
                 AS "Last Thursday in a year 2013" 
from dual
connect by level <= 12;

Comment: @wolφi - there doesn't seem to be; I guess you could replace `'THU'` with `to_char(date '2009-01-01', 'DAY')`, using any fixed date that you know is the right day of the week, which would make it session-safe, if a bit ugly.

Comment: @AlexPoole Good idea. I am just a bit puzzled that the language switch is missing...

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with `dbms_scheduler`:

```
declare
  start_dt              date := date '2013-01-01';
  months_last_thursday  date;

begin

  loop

    dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string (

       calendar_string   => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=-1 THU',
       start_date        =>  start_dt,
       return_date_after =>  start_dt, 
       next_run_date     =>  months_last_thursday

    );

    exit when months_last_thursday > date '2013-12-31';

    dbms_output.put_line(months_last_thursday);

    start_dt := months_last_thursday;

  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Rene's answer, this could be extended into a general (generic?) solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recurring_dates (p_year IN NUMBER, p_rule IN VARCHAR) 
  RETURN dbms_stats.datearray PIPELINED
AS
  start_dt DATE;
  last_dt  DATE;
  next_dt  DATE;
BEGIN
  start_dt := to_date(to_char(p_year,'fm0000')||'01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
  last_dt  := to_date(to_char(p_year,'fm0000')||'12-31','YYYY-MM-DD');
  LOOP
    dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string(
      calendar_string   => p_rule, 
      start_date        => start_dt,
      return_date_after => start_dt,
      next_run_date     => next_dt);
    EXIT WHEN next_dt > last_dt;
    PIPE ROW (next_dt);
    start_dt := next_dt;
  END LOOP;
END recurring_dates;
/
```

You'd feed the function with a calendar string in the `DBMS_SCHEDULER`-Syntax, and it will return the matching dates.

@rcmuthu786's last thursdays:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(recurring_dates (2013, 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=-1 THU'));

2013-01-31
2013-02-28
2013-03-28
2013-04-25
2013-05-30
...
```

Or, the second Wednesdays of each month:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(recurring_dates (2013, 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=2 WED'));
2013-01-09
2013-02-13
2013-03-13
2013-04-10
...
```

etc, etc...

Answer (score -1):

The most elegant way is the following

```
select thdate from (
select a.*, row_number() over (partition by to_char(thdate,'yyyymm'),day order by thdate desc) row_rank
 from (
select trunc(sysdate,'YEAR') + rownum-1 thdate,
trim(to_char(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR') + rownum-1,'DAY')) day from dba_objects 
where trunc(sysdate,'YEAR') + rownum-1 <
trunc(sysdate+365,'YEAR')
) a where day='THURSDAY'
) where row_rank=1
```